# After release codepush update app starting crash on users devices (react-native, android)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push, appcenter

We have recently released a code push patch for our android app in the play store. After enabling the code push release, the app installed on the user's phone started crashing.
So for debugging this issue by creating a test build and doing a dummy code push release(Just changing some text). we can see that the app started after installing the code push device on the test phone.

Is anyone facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to install or import from a new library in this new version you are releasing?

Codepush will only work with changes on the JS side, so if the new update has changes on the native side whether it's because of a new library you are using, or native code changes then you have to release a new version to the stores before you can rely on codepush again.

Comment: We didn't change anything in the native code. We just change the label inside the app(text inside JSX <Text> tag)

Comment: Can you provide the diff in the code between the stable version and the one you codepushed if possible

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the codepush version and the stable version is this. Just a label change.

[image]

Comment: @RodSar react native version: "0.67.0